# Is there any way to join stylus partials without actually compiling them?

Tags: stylus, brunch, broccolijs

Is there any way to join stylus partials without actually compiling them? I guess this would be the same as .SCSS files - so then it's a question of build tools. In codekit - you can join javascript files in this way / but that is because it's not a superset style language. I currently use broccoli or brunch depending on the stack, for my builds. I am not interested in trying any other build tools right now.

_thing-1.styl

```
html
  background: blue
```

_thing-2.styl

```
div
  background: red
```

_thing-3.styl

```
span
  color: yellow
```

app.styl

```
@import '_thing-1'
@import '_thing-2'
@import '_thing-3'
```

app.css

```
html {
  background: blue;
}

div {
  background: red;
}

span {
  color: yellow;
}
```

### and... THIS is what I want to have as well...

_master.styl

```
html
  background: blue

div
  background: red

span
  color: yellow
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this question is more about build tools and not Stylus itself, something like `gulp.concat` or simple `cat _thing-1.styl _thing-2.styl _thing-3.styl > _master.styl`

Comment: This led me in the right direction - *but* isn't very explicit for others - So I'll comment with my findings. Looks like with brunch as my build tool, I can use a call back `onCompile` and I'll look for the broccoli equivalent.

Thank you.